# Cross Domain request returns status code 0 in Firefox but 200 in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, cross-domain

I have code in a directive that is making a cross domain request. When it runs in Chrome, it works just fine. When it runs in Firefox or IE 11, I get a status code of 0 with no data. My code is:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'https://mycrossdomain.url'})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('success');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('error');
    })
```

In Firefox and IE I get "error" alerted and in Chrome I get "success" and I can view the data.

Why would this be happening? The server obviously supports cross domain requests because it works in Chrome. When I navigate to the URL in all browsers I get a response so it definitely exists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try comparing the request and response headers in Chrome vs Firefox to verify that they are the same. Also, what is alerted in each browser, "success" or "error"?

Comment: The headers are the same EXCEPT that in the Response headers, Chrome has "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = my server domain. This is not in the response from Firefox.

Comment: Also, I can see in the console of Firefox that I am getting a message "Cross-origin request blocked..." etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I needed to specify `withCredentials` like so:

```
$http.get('https://mycrossdomain.url', { withCredentials: true})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('success');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('error');
    })
```

This is because I needed to pass the user credentials (a certificate) to the other domain. Angular was unfortunately not providing very useful error messages.

Comment: But why was it working in Chrome? Seems like it should have failed in Chrome.

Comment: I am not sure, perhaps Chrome automatically passes credentials along for CORS requests.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce the bug in a public place, that would be great. This certainly sounds like a bug, Chrome should not send credentials without permission.

Comment: Unfortunately I am on a private network and am not able to share my client's code. It was very odd, the destination server returned a 500 in Firefox and IE (makes sense because the server expected credentials) whereas in Chrome I got 200 along with results.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯